# Kanakdhara stotra experience

Tags: stotra, lakshmi, maa, adi, shankaracharya

I have recently got to learn about the kanakdhara stotra, and was left awstruck by the story. For those who are not aware of it please have a look :

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanakadhara_Stotra#:~:text=Having%20nothing%20edible%20in%20her,praise%20of%20the%20goddess%20Lakshmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanakadhara_Stotra#:%7E:text=Having%20nothing%20edible%20in%20her,praise%20of%20the%20goddess%20Lakshmi).

https://www.shlokapreneurdivyaa.com/the-story-behind-the-kanakadhara-stotram/

I am curious to know, has anyone practised this stotra and has experienced any blessing or bliss from Maa lakshmi.

Answer (score 0):

The experience depends on understanding How Kanakadhara stand apart from hundreds of stotrams?
Many devotees and rishis expressed their love and admiration towards Iśvara (Ishwara) with hidden meaning and purpose through slokas, pattikas, poems, dandakams, and stotrams. Such literature concentrates on admiring the attributes and greatness of Ishwara, and yes they are undoubtedly exceptional. Some, on the other hand, was composed of listing Ishwara’s titles, and qualities like Astotrams or Sahastra Namavali. Some are to admire the beauty (Soundaryam, not physical beauty) and features of Ishwara, one such extraordinary composition by Sri Muka Shankarendra Saraswathi was Muka Pancha Shati, which describes Devi Kamakshi’s delightful Soundaryam. There are those that depict or narrate the accounts of Ishwara in various incarnations. Finally, there are those which are composed of addressing a specific need of devotees like stotrams dedicated towards prosperity, health, knowledge, holy matrimony, children and more. From all the above, Kanakadhara stands apart.
The answer is mind blowing. But to answer this question, my experience is was the same. I am going to present this [source link](https://sanatanadhara.com/kanaka-dhara/) so that you can further your experience and share back in the comments.